# Microsoft Edge overrules and overrides my CSS styles for html playback &#9654;

Tags: html, css, audio, microsoft-edge, playback

The newest version of MS Edge overrides all my CSS styles applied to the html charater for playback, making the playback button ugly and off in all respects for my webpage! Examine how FireFox and Chrome do respect my CSS styles (namely white background and gray color, thats it, clean and simple):

HTML

```
<audio>
    <p>&#9654;</p>
</audio>
```

CSS

```
audio p{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #BBB;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
```

---

FireFox and Chrome (perfect clean render according to my CSS):
[image]

---

Microsoft Edge (ugly custom button overlay, ignoring my own CSS styles!):
[image]

---

How can I make MS Edge listen to my CSS styles and stop auto-everythinging my webpage?

Comment: what _is_ your css?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb thanks for your question, in reply to your query I updated my question.

Comment: Try using inspect element to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After perusing all css items in the normal and comuted tab in EDGE, I cannot find anything awkward except as stated in the question: the html character `&#9654;` is replaced with a fancy button and I really only want MS EDGE to stop doing that and render the character as in all other browsers (see first printscreen by FireFox and Chrome)

Comment: If that's how Edge render the character there's nothing you can do to change it.

Comment: Except use a different character.